# Send Message to Users In Group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a group on azure, I have been able to get the members of the group using MS Graph API.

I have the details of the users in this format:

```
{
      '@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.user',
      id: 'xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx',
      businessPhones: [],
      displayName: 'USER__FULL_NAME',
      givenName: 'USER_FIRST_NAME',
      jobTitle: null,
      mail: 'USER_EMAIL',
      mobilePhone: null,
      officeLocation: null,
      preferredLanguage: 'en-US',
      surname: 'USER_LAST_NAME',
      userPrincipalName: 'USER_EMAIL'
}
```

I want to send a message to the members of the group using BotFramework Node.js SDK.

I have checked [Microsoft Bot Service Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), I can't find anything related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two approaches :

1. Using pro-active messages via the bot's Teams Channel.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet
2. if you do not need/want a bot that there are options to 'just' start a new 1:1 or group-chat with a Graph call.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Hi Jos, thanks for your time, the second approach seems to be related to what I want to achieve. However, after testing, I got error 401 with this error body 

```{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-05-27T08:59:41",
            "request-id": "cd95cfb4-8490-4981-a8d9-68432db139c9",
            "client-request-id": "cd95cfb4-8490-4981-a8d9-68432db139c9"
        }
    }
}```

I'm wondering If it has anything to do with Graph API chat permissons

Comment: a 401 error is definitely permission related.
You app will need to have UserDelegated permissions Chat.Create or Chat.ReadWrite

HTTP Status Code 401: The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.